# Short-cuts for gimp

Tags: gimp, shortcuts

I want to edit many jpg files and use the color curves tool to adjust each image with a individual color curve.

I could not find a keyboard short cut to open the curves tool. Is there any?

How to save the image back to the same jpg file with a non-interactive keyboard short-cut?

I know that perfectionists prefer other file formats, but in this case I have many jpg files and don't need xcf (extra cool format :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Gimp Keyboard Shortcuts

From the *Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts* menu we can assign a shortcut to almost any action we want. We may have to disable an existing identical shortcut if we want to assing the same key combination. In below example I had disabled <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> using <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on selecting a *new accelerator* to then assign <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to *Curves...* in the *Tools* section:

[image]

#### Gimp Save/Export/Overwrite

Similarly we can assign a shortcut to save our work. By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> will save a project in Gimps XCF format. In case we had edited another file format and would like to keep it we can assign *Overwrite* in the *File* section of the keyboard shortcuts to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

Alternatively we can export an image with the default <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> but then we'd have to always press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in addition.

#### Working with shortcuts

By this we can achieve a quite rapid workflow in that we can open multiple files, assign shortcuts to *Windows > Next Image*, do or work, overwrite the original file by keyboard shortcut above, save it, and lastly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> close that window/tab. As soon as we get used to this it will be a rather quick workflow.